# Can't install open ssh server in windows 10

Tags: windows-10, ssh, openssh

I am unable to install open ssh server in windows 10 .I have use the GUI methord (add optional features)but it did not worked then i checked it is already installed or not using powershell

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-WindowsCapability -Online | ? name -like "openssh*"
```

And the result was no

```
Name  : OpenSSH.Server~~~~0.0.1.0
State : NotPresent
```

Then I tried to install it using CLI methord

```
Add-WindowsCapability -Online -Name OpenSSH.Server~~~~0.0.1.0
```

But an error occured

```
    Add-WindowsCapability : The service cannot be started, either because it is disabled
or because it has no enabled devices associated with it.
At line:1 char:1
+ Add-WindowsCapability -Online -Name OpenSSH.Server~~~~0.0.1.0
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Add-WindowsCapability], COMException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Dism.Commands.AddWindowsCapabilityCommand
```

Please any one help me with the issue.

Comment: Does `Get-WindowsCapability` work?

Comment: `Get-WindowsCapability -Online -Name OpenSSH.Server~~~~0.0.1.0


Name         : OpenSSH.Server~~~~0.0.1.0
State        : NotPresent
DisplayName  : OpenSSH Server
Description  : OpenSSH-based secure shell (SSH) server, for secure key management and
               access from remote machines.
DownloadSize : 1291185
InstallSize  : 4947581` 
Is the output

Comment: Try these two commands: `Add-WindowsCapability -Online -Name OpenSSH.Client*` and `Add-WindowsCapability -Online -Name OpenSSH.Server*`.

Comment: No it did not worked .Thank you for your reply

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to install it myself by following this blog :https://www.saotn.org/manually-install-openssh-in-windows-server/

Comment: This worked for me on Windows Server 2019; thanks.