# Installing ssh server in windows 10

Tags: windows-10, ssh

I cant install ssh server in windows 10 as I mentioned in this post here: [Can't install open ssh server in windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/1688019/cant-install-open-ssh-server-in-windows-10?noredirect=1#comment2593942_1688019)

So i want to know is there any other way or third party way to install it in  windows 10 other than windows optional features or Add-WindowsCapability .

If any one know how to install it  please help me .

Comment: The built-in OpenSSH Server is the simplest method, it’s also one of the only, Windows binaries that exist that’s already prebuilt. Why can’t you use the built-in feature?

Comment: So in simple words i cannot be installed by third party or any other methord

Comment: It certainly can provided you compile a Windows compatible binary and install it. If those projects are still alive I could not say since the Microsoft fork of the OpenSSH Server daemon also doesn’t contain every feature of the OpenSSH daemon. Why exactly are you unable to use the built-in feature?

Comment: You can view  this post to see the problem:https://superuser.com/questions/1688019/cant-install-open-ssh-server-in-windows-10?noredirect=1#comment2593942_1688019

Comment: You have failed to provided the information required to answer that particular question.

Comment: Anyways [Here](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_windows_openssh_server#windows_older) provides an alternative to the OpenSSH Server optional Windows feature.  It's only ONE of the many options, since running a OpenSSH Server on Windows has always been possible, it just was more difficult before Microsoft made it an optional feature and was fully documented by Microsoft.

Comment: what information should I provide? I have provided the command I typed and the error I got. If I am missing something please tell me.

Comment: Windows build version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed it by following this post :https://www.saotn.org/manually-install-openssh-in-windows-server/